# Mapping dataframe columns to a MySQL table when column names and ncol do not match

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb, dbi, rmysql

MySQL's `INSERT INTO` command lets one specify column names in this way:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column5, column3, column8, ...)
VALUES (value1, value5, value3, value8, ...);
```

All other columns that are not provided in the command above will get an `NA` value in all corresponding rows. Is it possible to achieve the same in `R` when writing a dataframe to a MySQL table?

I am writing over 1000 dataframes from R to MySQL in a `for` loop. Not all these dataframes contain the same set of columns, but in all cases they contain at least 2 columns that correspond to columns in the MySQL table.

Is it possible to specify the mapping beforehand? For example, `value` column in R be mapped to `MEASUREMENT` column in the MySQL table, etc.

Comment: I don't think the `mysqlr` package allows for this behavior.  But, you may look into using another R-SQL package which allows you to write direct MySQL queries (which would make it possible).

Comment: `DBI` package allows the execution of SQL queries but I am more interested in finding out whether doing it via R in a straight-forward manner is at all possible.